# Compare two dataframes and choose the one based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, merge, many-to-many

So a bit complicated example, at least for me.  I have two dataframes.  They have different interval lengths and I have a few criteria in order to merge them.  I just don't know how to go about it.  There will be multiple HoleIDs.  Issue is overlapping intervals between both files and want the script to break it down if there is multiple values in each that it can break down to.

File1

```
HoleID,From,To,Value
DH-1,0,15,-99
DH-1,15,25,0.01
DH-1,25,100,0.022
```

File2

```
HoleID,From,To,Value
DH-1,0,5,0.08
DH-1,5,10,1
DH-1,10,25,0.04
DH-1,25,50,-99
DH-1,50,100,0.066
```

Want

```
HoleID,From,To,Value
DH-1,0,5,0.08
DH-1,5,10,1
DH-1,10,25,0.04
DH-1,25,50,0.022
DH-1,50,100,0.066
```

-99 = missing in this instance

1. File2 to take precendence over File1 when File1 has -99 as the value
2. If File1 to take precendence over File2 when File2 has -99
3. Merge/overwrite based off holeid (since there will be more than just one) and From/To intervals.
4. If a value exists for both File1 and File2, Let the Value in File 2 be chosen

Merge doesn't do it.

Comment: There is no difference between `File2` and `Want`.

Comment: Sorry, pasted wrong.  Now there is.

Comment: Please format code as code.

Comment: The only code I have currently is loading the two files as dataframes.  I don't know what the next step is.  I tried merge and it doesn't do what I need in the criterias 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge` the two frames on `HoleID` and `From` and conditionally update `Value` if equal to `-99` with `mask`:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1.drop('To', axis=1), on=['HoleID', 'From'], how='left', suffixes=['', '_y'])
df3['Value'] = df3['Value'].mask(df3['Value'] == -99, df3['Value_y'])
df3 = df3.drop('Value_y', axis=1)
df3
Out[1]: 
  HoleID  From   To  Value
0   DH-1     0    5  0.080
1   DH-1     5   10  1.000
2   DH-1    10   25  0.040
3   DH-1    25   50  0.022
4   DH-1    50  100  0.066
```

Comment: Will this work if they don't have the same intervals.  Say if one has 0 to 8 and the other has 0 to 5 and 5 to 10?

Comment: @CelesteWilson My answer is solely based off the `From` value, as you can see with `on=['HoleID', 'From']`